# Grab test's pass/fail from TestCase via TFS Rest API

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to grab the Outcome off of a testcase in TFS, looks something like this.

[image: really basic layout]

and I can't seem to find a straightforward way to do it.  I've tried to grab the workitem directly, query for the property with no success.  I was able to use the SDK to get the data (which I'm trying to avoid)

```
_tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(website)) { ClientCredentials = what };
_tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
var testService = _tfs.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
var aPoint = plan.QueryTestPoints("SELECT * FROM TestPoint WHERE TestCaseId = 10").SingleOrDefault();
console.Write(aPoint.MostRecentResultOutcome);
```

I have the ID for the testcase from the webhook so that's not a problem.  All I want is that "MostRecentResultOutcome".  Is there a way to get that data from the REST api in 1 call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Patrick said, you can't as of right now.  What I ended up doing its grabbing the ID and  System.TeamProject off of the webhook passing that along as such

```
    private TfsTeamProjectCollection _tfs;
    private ITestManagementTeamProject _project;
    private readonly ITestManagementService _service;

    public TfsThing(string instanceUrl, string user, string password)
    {
        var cred = new VssBasicCredential(user, password);
        _tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(instanceUrl)) { ClientCredentials = cred };
        _tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

        _service = _tfs.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
    }

    public string GetTestStatus(int id, string projectName)
    {
        var project = _service.GetTeamProject(projectName);
        var result = project.TestResults.ByTestId(id);

        return result.LastOrDefault()?.Outcome.ToString();
    }
```

This was the shortest way I found -- may not be the most efficient though

Incase you were wondering, these are the two packages I used

```
Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client
Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use below [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/points#get-a-list-of-test-points) which will return a list of test points through test case ID according to your code info:

```
GET https://Fabrikam-Fiber-inc.VisualStudio.com/DefaultCollection/fabrikam-fiber-tfvc/_apis/test/plans/1/suites/1/points?testcaseid=39&api-version=1.0
```

Then will get a response with lastTestRun, lastResutl, outcome...

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/fabrikam-fiber-tfvc/_apis/test/Plans/1/Suites/1/Points/1",
      "assignedTo": {
        "id": "d291b0c4-a05c-4ea6-8df1-4b41d5f39eff",
        "displayName": "Jamal Hartnett"
      },
      "configuration": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Windows 8"
      },
      "lastTestRun": {
        "id": "28"
      },
      "lastResult": {
        "id": "100000"
      },
      "outcome": "Passed",
      "state": "Completed",
      "testCase": {
        "id": "39",
        "url": null,
        "webUrl": null
      },
      "workItemProperties": [
        {
          "workItem": {
            "key": "Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus",
            "value": "Not Automated"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "count": 1
}
```

Comment: That assumes I have the plan and suite ID, which the data in the webhook only gives me the ID for that given testcase -- can I get that data w/o a plan and a suite?

Comment: @jeriley Afraid not, it's not able to only use a test case ID to fetch the  recent test run result  info through REST API. And even  using the  old client api may also not do the trick.  Cause the new web-based test case management in TFS2015 or later which is not so compatibility with client api.

Comment: I figured as such.  I'll post an answer to show if someone has the same problem.